# ruby install gems - SSL connect returned certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rbenv

I am working on a rails project. I have been working with rails for a while, and use an old MacBook Pro (2012) that has seen ruby/rails development since 2014. In that time, I have both RVM, RBENV, rails versions from 3.2 to 5.1.0, ruby versions from 2.0.0 to 2.2.3 on my machine.

Recently, I have been able to get around the error

`SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)`

with installing gems via `http` and using `source 'http://rubygems.org'` in my gemfiles.

However, I would like to finally get rid of this issue. I have taken steps to improve this issue doing the following:

1. following this guide https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88
2. which lead to this link https://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/#installing-using-update-packages
3. which lead to this link https://bundler.io/v1.16/guides/rubygems_tls_ssl_troubleshooting_guide.html#troubleshooting-certificate-errors

The steps I have currently taken were to do the following:
`brew update`

`brew install openssl-osx-ca`

`brew tap raggi/ale`

`brew upgrade openssl`

However, the result of running `gem update --system` returned the same error

`SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)`

The #3 solution, suggested using `rvm implode`, forcing `brew uninstall openssl --force` and starting over. I am very hesitant to do this, because I use rails in my day job and I don't want to show up (i use my machine) with a machine that cannot even turn on a rails server.

Has anyone had to perform something similar? Any actionable steps I could take to fix this SSL issue for once?

Comment: James, I remember installing/updating the rubygems manually by downloading https://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-update-2.7.7.gem Have you tried this method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this manual install instruction https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/UPGRADING.rdoc#manual-install

**OR**

1. Download latest rubygem package https://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-update-2.7.7.gem
2. Then install it

   ```
   gem install rubygems-update-2.7.7.gem
   ```

This worked for me and for my colleagues.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I ran `gem install rubygems-update` from that guide, but still  got the original error `Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)` which is the root of my problem. i can try downloading the latest gem package, but if i'm unable to do any installs of gems, i feel the would still be stuck with the same error above.

Comment: Don't run `gem install rubygems-update`. That's what I am trying to say earlier.

Comment: i was able to download the gem manually, moved to where my ruby/rails projects are, cd into it, ran `ruby setup.rb` and got the success message. Then, when i cd'd out of the folder, back into my home (root) folder where my rails projects are, and ran `gem update --system` i got new errors, but there were all errors that essentially read `SSL verification error at depth 2: certificate has expired (10)`. So that's a start, but do you know where I can go from here?

Comment: After `gem install rubygems-update-2.7.7.gem` I had to run `update-rubygems`